# Saving Custom Cycle List with cycle multiindex* list

Tags: pgfplots

I'd like to save a cycle list in PGFPlots that I have defined using `cycle multiindex* list`. See MWE below. When I try to do this though I just get black lines in my plot.

How can I save my custom list under a unique identifier?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer} 

\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.17,
    colormap/Set1,
}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{TestList}{
    cycle multiindex* list={
    mark list*\nextlist
    Set1\nextlist},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            cycle list name=TestList
        ]
        \addplot+ [domain=0:5] {x};
        \addplot+ [domain=0:5] {x^2};
        \addplot+ [domain=0:5] {10*sin(deg(x))};
        \addplot+ [domain=0:5] {10*cos(deg(x))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how to directly create such a `cycle list`. But you can create a *style* that incorporates the `cycle list` and than call it in the `axis` options.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.17
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
    \pgfplotsset{
        colormap/Set1,
        % define a style that incorporates the `cycle list`
        TestList cycle list/.style={
            cycle multiindex* list={
                mark list*\nextlist
                Set1\nextlist%
            },
        },
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        % call the defined style
        TestList cycle list,
    ]
        \addplot+ [domain=0:5] {x};
        \addplot+ [domain=0:5] {x^2};
        \addplot+ [domain=0:5] {10*sin(deg(x))};
        \addplot+ [domain=0:5] {10*cos(deg(x))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: That works. Thank you!